# MySQL query with WHERE clause, but drop a condition if no results?

Tags: mysql

I'm currently doing this via two separate queries from PHP, but would love to optimize and somehow in a single query.

First query..

```
SELECT `referrer` 
FROM `tbl_traffic_log` 
WHERE `domain` = 'mysite.com' 
  AND `referrer` != '$referringDomain' 
  AND CASE WHEN `clicks_in_unique`=0 THEN 2 ELSE `clicks_out_unique`/`clicks_in_unique` END < 1.4 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1
```

..and if mysql_num_rows shows no results, I do a second query to try again and check if there are any results minus the `referrer` != 'partner1.com' part.

The code is basically trying to find a random trade partner who ISN'T the partner who sent that click, but if there are no matches, as a last resort it's ok to send back, provided it matches the other criteria.

I'm pretty sure there is a way to do this, but just can't find a way after searching (probably because I'm not understanding the problem enough to type in the right thing).

Any other critique of the query is welcome as well.

Thank you :)

Comment: 2 queries are perfectly fine. Don't try to fit everything into 1 query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this like this:

```
SELECT `referrer` 
FROM `tbl_traffic_log` 
WHERE `domain` = 'mysite.com' 
  AND CASE WHEN `clicks_in_unique`=0 THEN 2 ELSE `clicks_out_unique`/`clicks_in_unique` END < 1.4 
ORDER BY `referrer` != '$referringDomain' desc, RAND() 
LIMIT 1
```

The idea is to put the condition in the `order by`.  The condition (in MySQL) evaluates to either 0 or 1, so we want where the condition is true first (hence the `desc`).  It then chooses a random row.  If there are no rows where the condition is true, then it chooses a random row.